# Find class more than one level deep in div layer - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a selector that will grab an image inside each bootstrap accordian panel heading. The code I have so far is, but this selector does not seem to be fining the $('accordion').find doesn't seem to be locating the heading. Any ideas?

JQuery:

```
 $('accordion').find('.panel-heading').each(function() {
        $(this).find('img').hide();
 })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                 Collapsible Group Item #1
                 <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control class1" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control class1" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
                <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control class2" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control class2" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="class2"> Check me out
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
                <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: `accordion` is the `id` of the element - you're missing the `#`. Try this: `$('#accordion').find(.....`

Comment: Yep that did it thanks :) - If you wanna pop it in as the answer I mark it as right if you like?

Comment: It's ok - it's just a typo that's not likely to help anyone else in the future. You're best to delete the question.

Comment: Yes true , I have deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the snippet you don't need to travel through foreach loop just one line method will do it for you.

Although in your case only "#" was missing it should be

```
 $('#accordion').find('.panel-heading').each(function() {
        $(this).find('img').hide();
    });
```

But I will prefer to use below one:

```js
$('#accordion .panel-heading img').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                            <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control class1" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control class1" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                                <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control class2" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control class2" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="class2"> Check me out
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                Collapsible Group Item #3
                                <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the # in your code.

```
 $('#accordion').find('.panel-heading').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').hide();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the # in the selector and also you don't need to use .each() method here. Like....

```
$('#accordion').find('.panel-heading img').hide();
```